# How to cluster temporal trajectories of various social network statistics

Tags: time-series, clustering, social-network

I have social network data for 100 open source repositories. The data consists of 12 snapshots (1 for every month of a year) of the networks for several repositories. Out of this I want to extract time series for various SNA characteristics/statistics, as in the tables below:

```
**Table: Repository #1**
    Centralization Connectedness Graph Hiearchy
Jan   .5            .8             .1
Feb   .6            .9             .2
Mar   .7            .7             .2

**Table: Repository #2**
    Centralization Connectedness Graph Hiearchy
Jan   .3            .5             .1
Feb   .6            .3             .4
Mar   .2            .7             .2

etc...until repository #100
```

Now I want to identify clusters of projects that have similar social network characteristics, as they progress over time. What is the most suitable technique for clustering projects according to multiple time series simultaneously?

Comment: A potentially useful post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26862/24000